# Webpack build produced nothing when I copied my project from one directory to another

Tags: webpack

In a project I am using Webpack to transpile sass to css and run babel. I copied the entire project from the project root to another directory, ran an npm install in the new project and then ran my npm build command to build my bundled js and css files.The webpack output showed success with all the entrypoints I expected, but no bundled js file or css file were generated. I didn't paste the config file contents here because there is no difference between file structures or configs between the working project and the one that doesn't work. Please let me know if you need to see them.I repeated the exercise and got the same results.
webpack.config.js

```
//Webpack configuration
// Allow import and export of javascript
// Allow css and sass (scss) files to be imported into the bundle

// Ensure absolute paths
const path = require('path');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './resources/js/main.js', output: {
    //bundle.js is the only file you include in your html to get all the goodies below
    filename: 'bundle.js',

    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
  },
  mode: 'none',
  module: {
    rules: [{
      //Allow css files to be imported into javascript module
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: [
        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader',
      ],
    },
      {
        // Allow scss files to be transpiled to css and imported into javascript module
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        // Babel transpile js to browser compatible js
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/env'],
            plugins: ['transform-class-properties'],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|svg)$/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 8000, // Convert images < 8kb to base64 strings
            name: 'images/[hash]-[name].[ext]',
          },
        }],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new TerserPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'main.css',
    }),
  ],
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "LetUsPray",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Website to choose prayer for you",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://gitlab.com/WeeMan/letuspray.git"
  },
  "author": "Ian Pritchard",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://gitlab.com/WeeMan/letuspray/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://gitlab.com/WeeMan/letuspray#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^3.5.3",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.9.0",
    "sass": "^1.26.5",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "file-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.1",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: You should paste the config. Does it contain any relative paths that may lead outside of the project? Did you reinstall the dependencies? Is the original code in a monorepo that may depend on files/configs outside of the project directory itself?

Comment: You should be able to edit your original post to add it. I took what you gave in the comment and put it up there, but you should update to include the rest. I'd also use the same code block formatting to include your webpack.config.js

Comment: Thanks. The whole config is there now. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: No worries. Did you also copy over hidden files from the original project? If you did just `cp path/to/src/* path/to/dst`, the `*` won't hit hidden files (like .babelrc). Also, while I suspect it shouldn't matter, can you add your `package.json` above (just use another code block, so it shows up separately from `webpack.config.js`

Comment: the package.json is added now. I used windows for the copy / paste on the entire root of the project. Will that get all of the hidden files?

Comment: I'm not seeing anything obvious. If you are using windows, it probably copied over (it doesn't treat files that start with a "." as hidden). If this is up somewhere that we can pull it and try to replicate, that would be useful.

Comment: Well, I didn't find out the cause of the issue, but pushing the working code to gitlab and then cloning it into the second directory worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find out the cause of the issue, but pushing the working code to gitlab and then cloning it into the second directory instead of copying all the files solved the issue!